# python calculate delta time between dict values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict with submission dates. I want to calculate how many days there are between every submmission. For now I put the dates in a list, but when I want to calculate the days it gives me an error.

I even tried filling the emtpy spots with the previous date, so that the days inbetween them would be 0. That also gave me the ValueError seen below.

The code I am using as if now:

```
days_inbetween = []
    
    for i in time_list:
        index = time_list.index(i)
        # print(index)
        if i == '':
            # print(i)
            continue
        else:
            try:
                days = datetime.strptime(time_list[index + 1], time_format) - datetime.strptime(i, time_format)
                # print(days)
                days_inbetween.append(days.days)
                     
            except:
                    days = datetime.strptime(time_list[-1], time_format) - datetime.strptime(i, time_format)
                    days_inbetween.append(days.days)

    print(days_inbetween)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

This is the dictionary

from:

"User": {
        "US01": "7-10-2020 05:49",
        "US02": "8-10-2020 06:09",
        "US03": "12-10-2020 06:05",
        "US04": "14-10-2020 12:17",
        "US05": "14-10-2020 12:17",
        "US06": "21-10-2020 07:11",
        "US07": "21-10-2020 07:11",
        "US08": "23-10-2020 06:36",
        "US09": "27-10-2020 06:42",
        "US10": "27-10-2020 06:42",
        "US11": "28-10-2020 08:28",
        "US12": "",
        "US13": "28-10-2020 08:28",
        "US14": "",
        "US15": "",
        "US16": "",
        "US17": "29-10-2020 16:22"
    }



To:

"User": {
        "US01": "3 days",
        "US02": "2 days",
        "US03": "2 days",
        "US04": "0 days",
        "US05": "6 days",
        "US06": "0 days",
        "US07": "1 days",
        "US08": "4 days",
        "US09": "0 days",
        "US10": "1 days",
        "US11": "0 days",
        "US12": "not done",
        "US13": "1 days",
        "US14": "not done",
        "US15": "not done",
        "US16": "not done",
        "US17": "1 days"
    }
```

This is the error I get: [image: The list you see are the values from the dict(time_list)]

Comment: there are some empty strings in your data if you handle that your error will be resolved

Comment: The empty strings are there because the assesments was not submitted. So there can't be a date on something which has not been submitted.

Answer (score 1):

Just like  deadshot wrote.

your having 4 empty strings inside your dates, I marked them for you:

[image]

"ValueError: time data **' '** does not match format '%d-%m-%Y %H:%M'"

Comment: I can not fill the empty strings, because there is no data for it. The student did NOT hand the assesment in. He did NOT make the assesment. So there is no date for something you did not submit.

Comment: Ah I see, in that case you will have to check if there is an empty string before you calculate the days, in case you find an empty string, then append "999" days or something like this that will be clear that the studnet did not hand the assesment.

do you think it will solve your problem ?

Comment: Now I figured out to replace the empty strings with the previous date. The problem with that is that there are some students who only submitted the first assesment. So there is no date before the first US. The dictionary can't fill the empty string if there is no previous date. I still get the same error as shown above in the img.

Comment: maybe you shouldn't replace the empty strings with the previous date.

I would have changed the empty strings to a future date like:
if it's an empty string then change it to 31-12-3000 00:00

maybe it will help you find out those who didn't submit and will handle the rest of the submittions.